# Invalid argument error when using tf.reshape()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am using some MNIST tutorials on convolutional neural networks to develop my own which can classify 15x15 into one of two classes.

When defining the convolutional network I have encountered an invalid argument error but I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Here is the code I am using to define the conv net:

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64])),
           'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3*3*64,1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
           'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 15, 15, 1])

conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + 
biases['b_conv2'])
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1, 3*3*64])
fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']

return output
```

The error it throws looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 4096 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 576
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MaxPool_1, Reshape_1/shape)]]
```

I can see where the `tf.reshape()` is requesting a tensor of size 576, however I don't understand where the tensor of size 4096 is coming from.

Comment: You have not shown us how you are calling `convolutional_neural_network(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us how exactly you perform the convolution and pooling, but most probably `strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]` in `conv2d` and `strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]` in `maxpool2d`, and `padding='SAME'` in both of them.

In this case, the shape of `conv1` tensor is `(?, 8, 8, 32)`, so `conv2` tensor is `(?, 4, 4, 64)`, not `(?, 3, 3, 64)`. When you pass a batch size equal to 4, tensorflow tries to reshape `(4, 4, 4, 64)` to `[-1, 3*3*64]` and fails - that's where 4096 is coming from.

A solution is to use `conv2.shape[1] * conv2.shape[2] * conv2.shape[3]` instead of hard-coded `3*3*64`, so that the code is more robust to the input image size and convolutional and pooling settings.